# Best Practice XML nillable vs minOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm consuming a WebService making around 3000 requests per batch in an overnight process.

I'm redefining some elements of the XSD.

For elements which have no content, is it preferable to make that element nillable thus retaining a consistent comparative structure to the XML, or, to set minOccurs=0 on those elements, thus reducing the weight of the XML payload?

I'm looking for what would be considered Best Practice and why would one approach be better than the other?

Comment: Please show us a sample of the XML documents and of the XML Schema you use for validation. `minOccurs="0"` on elements does not make them empty, but we really need to see the relevant definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both. The standard Java (jaxb) and .NET scvutil interpret them different or ignore one of them. It can depend on the parser and the generated code.

As this doesn't seem a problem, use minOccurs=0, so you don't have to supply the element and save a few bytes.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I'm really looking for justifications why I should adopt one over the other.